# How to string-override main menu items?

Tags: 7, routes, string-overrides

String Overrides is working perfectly for built-in Drupal output such as admin menu links, and for custom code that uses t().

However, it doesn't work if I try and override text in the main menu links. These are standard main menu links, not created by custom code or anything. I've been told this is possible and shown a site where it has been done, apparently with no extra customisation.

It's not a theming issue, since the problem remains when I switch to Bartik.

Should it be possible out of the box to override these strings and if so, any suggestions where I might be going wrong?

The same string is being overridden successfully in other places, just not in the menu.

EDIT: Turns out the site that "it was working on" had been done manually, so never mind

Comment: Does [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84947/menu-links-not-being-translated) help?

Comment: It might be a way to do it but seems overkill. Also the site that is working does not have that module installed. Thanks though!

Comment: why not use hooks to do it ?
many exemples [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/change-menu-link-title-dynamically)

Comment: Do you mean use hooks to replace the menu titles with the desired strings? Surely it would be easier just to go into the menu settings and change them there