# Menu link Translation

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I'm using [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) and submodules to translate an English Language site to Spanish. I'm also using Automatic path aliases.

The issue is that menu links are directly to the node: `node/42.` When in the Spanish part of the site, `/es/` the links take me to `es/node/42`, not to the aliased url.

The best answer I've seen is [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84947/menu-links-not-being-translated) "Afterwards, you can arrange your menu links as you need them. I use parent/child URL aliases based on menu hierarchy, so I make a mirror menu tree." I don't know what he means, but it sounds like what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Hi, @icicleking. You might get more replies if you post details about your configuration.

Comment: Any feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be because of the "language detection" configuration.

So check this configuration via *Configuration -> Languages -> detection and selection*: the order should be 'URL, Default, User', and not something like 'Default, URL, User'.

Comment: Shouldn't default always be last? Otherwise it would not make sense to have user specific languages...

Comment: That might work too